# String.IsNullOrEmpty Monad

Tags: c#, string, functional-programming, null, monads

I have lately been dipping my feet into the fascinating world of functional programming, largely due to gaining experience in FP platforms like React and reading up on blogs the likes of https://blog.ploeh.dk/.  As a primarily imperative programmer, this has been an interesting transition, but I am still trying to get my wet feet under me.

I am getting a little tired of using `string.IsNullOrEmpty` as such.  So much of the time I find myself littering my code with expressions such as

```
_ = string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? "default text here" : str;
```

which isn't so bad as it goes, but say I wanted to chain a bunch of options past that null, e.g.

```
_ = string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? (
    util.TryGrabbingMeAnother() ??
    "default text here") : str;
```

Yuck.  I'd much rather have something like this --

```
_ = monad.NonEmptyOrNull(str) ??
    util.TryGrabbingMeAnother() ??
    "default text here";
```

As the sample indicates, I am using a function that I am referring to as a monad to help reduce `string.IsNullOrEmpty` to a null-chainable operation:

```
public string NonEmptyOrNull(string source) =>
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(source) ? null : source;
```

My question is, is this proper terminology?  I know `Nullable<T>` can be considered a monad (see [Can Nullable be used as a functor in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48488178/can-nullable-be-used-as-a-functor-in-c/48490711#48490711) and [Monad in plain English? (For the OOP programmer with no FP background)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704652/monad-in-plain-english-for-the-oop-programmer-with-no-fp-background/2704795#2704795)).  These materials are good references, but I still don't have quite enough an intuitive grasp of the subject to know if I'm not just being confusing or inconsistent here.  For example, I know monads are supposed to enable function chaining like I have above, but they are also "type amplifiers" -- so my little example seems to *behave* like a monad for enabling chaining, but it seems like converting null/empty to just null is a *reduction* rather than an amplification, so I question whether this actually *is* a monad.  So for this particular application, could someone who has a little more experience with FP tell me whether or not it is accurate to call `NonEmptyOrNull` a monad, and why or why not?

Comment: `NonEmpty` and `Option` (or `Nullable`) are both monads, so you can combine them to get the desired type. You cannot compose monads in general but you can write a function that extends a monad by the semantics of another one. This approach is referred to as monad transformers. Anyway, I'd advice you to learn functors and applicative functors first, because monads are also functors and the latter determine about 80% of their semantics. I've been writing an FP course in case you are interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like a *filter* operation. In C#, you'd idiomatically call it `Where`. It may be easier to see if we make the distinction between absent and populated values more explicit, which we can do with [the Maybe container](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/03/26/the-maybe-functor):

```
public static Maybe<T> Where<T>(
    this Maybe<T> source,
    Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return source.SelectMany(x => predicate(x) ? x.ToMaybe() : Maybe.Empty<T>());
}
```

There's only a few [containers](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/01/14/functors-are-containers) that support filtering. The two most common ones are `Maybe` (AKA `Option`) and various collections (i.e. `IEnumerable<T>`).

In Haskell (which has a more powerful type system than C#) [this is enabled](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Monad.html#g:5) via a class named `MonadPlus`, but I think that the type class `Alternative` actually ought to be enough to implement filtering. `Alternative` [is described](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Applicative.html#g:2) as a *monoid on applicative functors.* I'm not sure that that's particularly helpful, though.

With the above `Where` method, you could thread `Maybe` values through checks like `IsNullOrEmpty` like this:

```
var m = "foo".ToMaybe();
var inspected = m.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

This will let `m` pass through unchanged, while the following will not:

```
var m = "".ToMaybe();
var inspected = m.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

You could do the same with `Nullable<T>`, but I'll leave that as an exercise

It's also possible that you could do it with the new *nullable reference types* language feature of C# 8, but I haven't tried yet.

Comment: So I suppose if I were to do what I am trying to do with proper `Maybe`s, it would involve each of the potentially empty strings being a `Maybe<string>` and doing some nested `Match` or fallback calls.

Comment: @Bondolin You don't have to deal with nested Maybes. That's what `SelectMany` is for; it flattens as you go.

Answer (score 2):

A monad is a triple consisting of:

- A single-argument type constructor `M`
- A function `unit` of type `a -> M a`
- A function `join` of type `M (M a) -> M a`

which satisfies the monad laws.

A type constructor is a type-level function which takes a number of type arguments and returns a type. C# doesn't have this feature directly but when encoding monads, you need a single-argument generic type e.g. `List<T>`, `Task<T>` etc. For some generic type `M` you therefore need two functions which construct an instance of the generic type from a single value, an 'flattens' a nested instance of the type. For example for `List<T>`:

```
public static List<T> unit<T>(T value) { return new List<T> { value }; }
public static List<T> join<T>(List<List<T>> l) { return l.SelectMany(l => l); }
```

From this definition you can see that a single function cannot satisfy the definition ofa monad, so your example is not an example of a monad.

By this definition, `Nullable<T>` also does not have a monad instance since the nested type `Nullable<Nullable<T>>` cannot be constructed, so `join` cannot be implemented.

Comment: I didn't know that nested nullables are disallowed, but it seems to be a special (deliberate) quirk of the language rather than a fundamental property of the conceptual type. You *can* implement `SelectMany` (monadic *bind*), so the situation is unclear. Usually, if you have *bind*, you can implement `join`, or the other way around, but not here, because of the C# special case. For all practical cases, though, I'd consider `Nullable<T>` a monad.

Comment: @MarkSeemann - You can implement `SelectMany` but not `pure` since `pure(null)` must return `null` instead of `{HasValue: true, Value: null}`. This means the left idenitty law is broken since `pure(null).SelectMany(_ => 3)` is `null` instead of `3` as required. But yes, for practical purposes it's probably ok to think of `Nullable<T>` as having a monad instance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is usually solved in the FP paradigm a step ahead of validating `null`. The `str` value must never be `null`. Instead the original method must return an empty collection. This way the chaining of methods do not have to validate null. The next operation will not execute since there are no elements to operate on

There are multiple references you can find. related to this on the internet. https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2133373&seqNum=5 is one I could quickly grab

I learnt this from Zoran Horvat course in Pluralsight. If you do have access please check it out. The course name is "
Tactical Design Patterns in .NET: Control Flow" and the module is "Null Object and Special Case Patterns"

Taking about interest in FP, Zoran Horvat  also has other courses that help convert or make OO code more fuctional. I'm quite excited in responding here because lately I've been looking into FP as well. Good luck!